# An integrally closed subdomain of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $\mathbb{C} \subset R \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be a noetherian integral domain.

Further assume that:
(1) $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is separable over $R$.
(2) $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is algebraic over $R$ (integral, if this helps).
(3) The field of fractions of $R$ is $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Do NOT assume that:
(4) $R$ is integrally closed.
(5) $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a flat $R$-module.

My question: What additional conditions, which are not one of (4) or (5), are needed in order to guarantee the normality of $R$ or the flatness of $R \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

(In a more specific $R$ I have in mind, I can show that normality of $R$ is equivalent to flatness of $R \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$).

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: (i) Notice that I do not require to know when such $R$ is regular; normal is enough.
(ii) I am familiar with Serre's criterion for normality, but I do not know how it may help me in my specific case.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Condition (3) already implies (2)-that is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is algebraic over $R$. If you assume integrality, then $R$ is normal if and only if $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: Thanks. I should have written $\mathbb{C} \subset R \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and not  $\mathbb{C} \subset R \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: I could have deleted condition (2), but wanted to remain it for the integral case. I was not clear enough, but what I meant is that in my "specific" case I have in mind, I do not know if $R$ is normal and I do not know if $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and I am looking for a condition which will guarantee the normality of $R$ (and then, in the integral case, I will get that $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, which is what I really need..).

Comment: And truly, even without assuming integrality, if I will know that $R$ is normal, then I will be able to show that $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, using other considerations which are dependent on the specific case I have in mind. (There are other details I have not mentioned).